# Popup menu is accumulating occurrences (not dismissing properly)

Tags: android, popupmenu

I have a strange bug in my app. I have a RecyclerView containing list items with an icon for an overflow menu. See below.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFElL.png)

The problem occurs when I touch outside of the menu (to cancel it). The next time I select the menu it renders 2 menus. This continues for as many times as I go through the motions. See below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQzFi.png)

I can't figure out why this is happening. Here is my code for displaying the menu in a ViewHolder's list item:

```
final PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(mContext, mOptionsMenu);

                mOptionsMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_edit_delete_dq_competitor);

                        Menu menu = popupMenu.getMenu();
                        MenuItem edit = menu.findItem(R.id.edit);
                        MenuItem delete = menu.findItem(R.id.delete);
                        MenuItem dq = menu.findItem(R.id.dq);
                        MenuItem undoDq = menu.findItem(R.id.undo);

                        // change options if this competitor is DQ
                        if (competitor.getStatus() == Status.DQ) {
                            edit.setVisible(false);
                            delete.setVisible(false);
                            dq.setVisible(false);
                            undoDq.setVisible(true);
                        }
                        popupMenu.show();
                    }
                });
```

And here is my code for when a menu item is selected:

```
      popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.edit:
                                // todo finish this
//                                Intent intent = CompetitorInMatchForm.editIntent(mContext, competitor, true);
//                                startActivity(intent);
                                break;
                            case R.id.delete:
                                CompetitorStatusInMatchDialog deleteDialog = CompetitorStatusInMatchDialog.newInstance(competitor, "delete", getAdapterPosition());
                                deleteDialog.setTargetFragment(CompsInMatchFragment.this, REQUEST_ACTION);
                                deleteDialog.show(manager, DELETE_COMP_FROM_MATCH);
                                break;
                            case R.id.dq:
                                CompetitorStatusInMatchDialog dqDialog = CompetitorStatusInMatchDialog.newInstance(competitor, "dq", getAdapterPosition());
                                dqDialog.setTargetFragment(CompsInMatchFragment.this, REQUEST_ACTION);
                                dqDialog.show(manager, DELETE_COMP_FROM_MATCH);
                                break;
                            case R.id.undo:
                                CompetitorStatusInMatchDialog undoDialog = CompetitorStatusInMatchDialog.newInstance(competitor, "undo", getAdapterPosition());
                                undoDialog.setTargetFragment(CompsInMatchFragment.this, REQUEST_ACTION);
                                undoDialog.show(manager, DELETE_COMP_FROM_MATCH);
                                break;
                            default:
                                popupMenu.dismiss();
                        }

                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

Any help identifying why the dialog accumulates menu occurrences would be great.I have use popup menus before without this problem. I expect that it is dismissed when you touch outside of the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you inflate the menu inside the onClick listener, thus actually adding all the elements every time the menu is displayed.

If you expect that `dismiss` will remove the items from the menu, that's wrong: it will only hide the popup.

You can move this line outside of the listener:

```
popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_edit_delete_dq_competitor);
```

like this:

```
final PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(mContext, mOptionsMenu);
popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_edit_delete_dq_competitor);
```

Comment: Thank you. I was suspecting something like that was the case. I often confuse inflating the views with displaying them.